# Fill python string with date time as per format in string

Tags: python

I have a string which looks like:

`dt_string='some_prefix/%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M/some_postfix'`

I want to format this string with current date and time, so that it may look like `'some_prefix/2016-06-28/10:00/some_postfix'`

But my problem is that the date patterns may not always be in `%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M`. It can be anything like `%m-%d-%Y/%H:%M`. I looked into `datetime.datetime.strptime` but it takes format as input. In my case, the format isn't fixed. Is there a function that can determine the date time format dynamically from the input string? Or shall I write a logic determine format, and then use `datetime.datetime.strptime` ?

Comment: How about just using string interpolation directly? You could populate a dictionary with values for Y, m, M, d, H, etc and then just populate the string from there. This way it would be format agnostic, as long as you give all possible argument mappings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use time.strftime method

```
import time
time.strftime("stuff/%d-%m-%y/%H:%M/stuff")
```

Reference can be found here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-get-current-date-time-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt1 = 'some_prefix/%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M/some_postfix'
dt2 = 'some_prefix/%m-%d-%Y/%H:%M/some_postfix'

def fill_date(dt_str):
    d = datetime.now()
    filled = dt_str.replace('%Y', str(d.year))\
                   .replace('%m', str(d.month))\
                   .replace('%d', str(d.day))\
                   .replace('%H', str(d.hour))\
                   .replace('%M', str(d.minute))
    return filled

print(fill_date(dt1))
> 'some_prefix/2016-6-28/13:41/some_postfix'
print(fill(date(dt2))
> 'some_prefix/6-28-2016/13:42/some_postfix'
```

This should work in all cases, as long as they use the same % naming conventions.  It also won't mind if a string happens to be missing one of the fields (like maybe no time and only the date) or you can add a seconds to the replace chain if there's a chance seconds show up.